# How to format date (in msdate format) from EXCEL in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, momentjs, mat-table, js-xlsx

I'm currently working and learning Angular. The current project I'm working on requires me to display the content of an excel file.

I found this code very useful and informative. It helped me a lot with my current project.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read-and-export-excel-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsheet%2Fsheet.component.ts

My only question is, How do I format the date on the template?

[image]

I guess my questions are:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" multiple="false" />
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
            <td *ngFor="let val of row">
                {{val}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

On the HTML above,

How can I tell that the data type of val is date?
Then if it's a date, how can I format it into example, yyyy-mm-dd?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Angular provides few alternatives, please look into: 
- https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe
- https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate

Answer (score 0):

You need to install moment.

You can follow these links [(1)](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/00-use-it/09-typescript/) [(2)](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/10-plugins/02-msdate/)

You received the data as an array. You need to loop over that data and for values in column 4:

if TBA => do nothing;

else => grab that data, convert to int, than

```
moment.fromOADate(convertedInt);
```

than replace it.

Once your data is reprocessed it'll show in the table with your current html-code.

Comment: Please don't use moment - [it has been deprecated](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

Comment: Check the link.

Comment: @Phuzi, sorry, too fast. O.K. In the lnk they mention some alternatives. You (= user3604379) needs to figure out which one can do the same thing as is described in the answer.